# when i use SDWebimage to load image,i want to know how the image is loaded,but the Cell is nonfluency

Tags: objective-c

I want to achieve when image is not loaded, the `imageView` load default image. But when the image is loaded,the `imageView` load the url-image. Now the problem is that the `Sington` (`SDImageCache`) should cause nonfluency. When I shield the `Sington` (`SDImageCache`), it's ok.

```
BOOL isInCache = ([[SDImageCache sharedImageCache]
    imageFromCacheForKey:imgUrlStr] != nil);    
if (isInCache) {   
    [self.imgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrlStr] 
        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImg"] 
        options:SDWebImageRetryFailed];
} else {    
    self.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImg"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using below code in my application.

```
[IMAGE_VIEW_OBJECT_NAME sd_setImageWithURL:IMAGE_URL placeholderImage:PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    if(error)
    {
        _imgUserPic.image = PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE;
    }
    else
    {
        _imgUserPic.image = image;
    }

}];
```

Its help me to show default image when the image is not available on the main URL.

Hope it will work for you.